# Update all records with method in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've imported a bunch of locations from a CSV file and now I need to get them geocoded. When I create a new record by hand I run a `:geocode` after validations. I'd like to be able to run that on all the records at once.

I've looked into `update_all` but haven't been able to get it to work. Is there a way to do this?

Here's my model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  default_scope order('locations.name ASC')

  acts_as_gmappable             

  attr_accessible               :name,
                                :address, 
                                :city,
                                :province,
                                :postal_code,
                                :country,
                                :phone,
                                :ext,
                                :phone_alt,
                                :ext_alt,
                                :url, 
                                :latitude, 
                                :longitude 

  geocoded_by                   :address

  validates_presence_of         :name
  validates_presence_of         :address
  validates_presence_of         :city
  validates_presence_of         :province
  validates_presence_of         :postal_code
  validates_presence_of         :country


  after_validation              :geocode


  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.address} #{self.city} #{self.province} #{self.postal_code} #{self.country}" 
  end                          
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update_all is for executing a database update statement on your records, so you could `Location.update_all("SET postal_code=null")` to clear out all the postal code fields. For your case it sounds like you just want to run your method on a batch of location objects.

How about:

```
Location.all.each do |loc|
  loc.geocode
end
```

Comment: This is kind of working but I think because it's in a loop the API is kicking a lot of them back. Is there a way to add a delay between each or something?

Comment: What do you mean, kicking them back? If all you want to do is slow the loop down, you could add a sleep(5) after each geocode request. If the logic is more involved than that--if there's some kind of follow-up required in the event of failure, I would suggest refactoring this into a custom rake task: http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks